# Style bug: "Make public" button overlaps with text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story, profile-page

In the Developer Story Preferences page, the button to create a public link overlaps with the column on the right (see picture).

I am using Firefox 49 on Ubuntu 16.04 with a resolution of 1920x1080 and the Firefox window maximised.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed now, it'll be live in the next production build. Feel free to ping me here if it's still not fixed.